# Why doesn't the svg image worked in vite with less?

Tags: javascript, svg, less, vite

language: vue 3.0 | vite | less
I set a SVG file in the less code like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhgVT.png)

When I use the vite builds result in a QTWebengine, it shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AEMo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m8CI.png)
And it did not work.
But if I set the url value with quotes like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXchs.png)
the svg image worked.

But I don't know how to use vie config or less config to do that in building.
I found so many ways in Google, nothing can help me. Thanks for everyone~!

I tried to set background-image value like this:
`background-image: url(~'@/assets/images/i_arrow_left.svg');`

```
@a: '@/assets/images/i_arrow_left.svg';
@url: 'url("@{a}")';
background-image: @url;
```

they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you're encountering is related to the path you're using in your Less configuration. In Vite, paths should be relative to the root of your project. Here's how you can correctly reference your SVG file:

```less
// Define the path relative to the project root
@a: "/src/assets/images/i_arrow_left.svg"; 

// Use the path in the background-image property
.background-image {
  background-image: url(@a);
}
```

Have you tried this way? Feel free to provide more details or any error messages you're encountering for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I tried this way today, but it still didn't work. The error is the same as the picture I send in question(enter image description here enter image description here). It looks like the path includes "（）", so it causes the problem.